# Error in Crystal Reports : Load report failed

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i am having a issue using crystal reports... this error occurs only in my application  web IIS

When i try to load a doc .rpt one exception is throwed with only one message :

Load report failed.

the same code in localhost works fine...

Here is my method to create the doc:

```
 try
    {
        Log("entered the crystal method");
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CookiePA"];
        Log("loaded the cookies");
        var docCrystal = new ReportDocument();
        Log("created the class -> ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();");

        string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/alu/ANEXO_CONTRATO_EDUCACIONAIS.rpt");
        Log("Report path: " + reportPath);

        docCrystal.Load(Server.MapPath("~/alu/ANEXO_CONTRATO_EDUCACIONAIS.rpt")); //erro occurs here

        Log("loaded the crystal report file");
        docCrystal.SetDatabaseLogon("consultarelestag", "PASS", "IP_PUBLIC_NUMBER\\SQL01", "SITE");
        Log("logged in to crystal");

        docCrystal.SetParameterValue("@MATRICULA", Convert.ToInt32(ObjLogin.intMatricula));
        docCrystal.SetParameterValue("@IP", ipAddress);
        Log("passed the parameters");

        var attachmentName = "CONT_ENF_" + ObjLogin.intMatricula + "_" + (DateTime.Now).ToString("ddMMyyyy_HH_mm_ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".pdf";
        Log("created file name ->" + attachmentName);
        docCrystal.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Server.MapPath("~/alunos/anexo/" + attachmentName));
        Log("generated the file");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("The following error occurred: ", ex);
    }
```

I have created a log .txt to see where is the exactly moment where the erro occurs and the code stops here :

docCrystal.Load(Server.MapPath("~/alu/ANEXO_CONTRATO_EDUCACIONAIS.rpt"));

I checked if the runtime of crystal is the same in my pc and in the server.. both of them use the version:SP 34 of the runtime, also i checked the pool application and set the Enable 32Bits to true.. and still doesn't work

PS: the location of the document is OK, the path have ANEXO_CONTRATO_EDUCACIONAIS.rpt

Answer (score 0):

Update!

after i remove `<identity impersonate="true"/>` in Web.config worked!